# Can I boot from a hard drive which contains a copy of the entire filesystem?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, macbook, bootable-media

I have a MacBook Air, which has a 120GB SSD. I copied the entire file system to another hard drive by just click-and-dragging the root directory. Is it possible boot from this hard drive? I know I can't boot from it how it is now, but is there a way to make it bootable? And if there is, will any data be lost relative to the original SSD?

Comment: I'm less familiar with the FS used by MacOS but this doesn't work with Windows. You need parts of the drive that are not files that explain how and where the files are that need to load the OS when the BIOS goes looking for it to boot. Sometimes you may be able to "repair" the necessary portions of the hard drive given you have all of the files.

Comment: You would be better off using something like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) [which has a free trial mode] & will ensure not only that the copy is bootable, but also that it contains a Recovery Partition. macOS btw uses an EFI partition to boot, it also needs the boot partition to be 'blessed' by the OS. If you only have the single 'boot' partition you will struggle to add the additional partitions to make it actually recognised correctly. CCC will just do it all for you.